# Amazon s3 image with https request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have an image fetching "dynamically" from amazon s3 bucket, here is the source example: src = http://s3.amazonaws.com/kidslink_assets/logos/5082f5d279216d14d000001e/original.png?1350759890

i need this to be a http*s* (https) request.

Comment: What's wrong with putting an https in place of the http. Looks like it's working.

Comment: how to configure ssl for anazon s3 bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote below code in application_controller. It's working fine.

```
 private 
 def redirect_https
   if Rails.env.production?
     redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless request.ssl?
   end
   true
 end
```